# How to change field of view (FOV) in PAYDAY The Heist for PC?

Tags: payday-the-heist

I've read [Tweaks (FOV workaround, increase settings, run on older systems!)](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2255947) but it suggests to change the aspect ratio, which makes the picture too flattened. Is there other way to change Field of view?

Comment: If you check the first row: "NOTE: This thread may be useless now thanks to the new official patch! Thanks devs! Find info here - http://forums.steampowered.com/forum....php?t=2280136 - I'll update the post if there are any settings still worth changing, or if you find something worth changing post it." I belive this is not available anymore.

Comment: Changing aspect ratio is still available, I've checked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is available in Options > Video > Advanced.  The FOV can be set between 60° and 100°, and the aiming FOV can reach 75°.

[image]

Comment: Is it been added recently? Because when I played it I didn't see such option

Comment: I'm asking myself exacty the same question: I have no idea.  There's no trace of it in the changelog, so I don't have a clue...

Comment: @DIMEDROLL Yes, it was not present in early versions of the game, and was added with a patch, along with alienware support and color filters.